# Relational Data using dropdowns and jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is almost more of a hypothetical before I even start getting into the coding, but has anyone had any experience for the following requirement...

Essentially, on my site I'll have 2 dropdowns.

Dropdown 1 - Options are A, B and C.

Dropdown 2 - Options are 1, 2, 3 and 4.

So what I'm looking to do if I select Option A in dropdown 1, I'll be able to select 1, 2, 3 and 4 in dropdown 2.

However, if I select Option B, I'll only be able to select 1 and 2 for example. Then Option C can only select 4 etc if that makes sense.

I've done it before by actually having different dropdowns with the relevant data and showing/hiding them depending on what was picked in dropdown 1, but I'm wondering if I'm making a rod for my own back with this method.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Regards,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Your method sounds fine to me, as long as it doesn't confuse some form submission (etc) that you want to use. But if you want to keep things in the same dropdown, one option might be to mark your options somehow and then modify them using jquery:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" class="noB">3</option>
<option value="4" class="noB">4</option>
```

Then attach a change event to your first dropdown:

```
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function(event) {
    if ($('#dropdown1').val() === 'B') {
        $('option.noB').removeAttr('selected').attr('disabled', true).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('option.noB').removeAttr('disabled').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```